# Send random Images with Hikari Python

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm new to coding and i would like to ask if anybody knows if it's possible to send (**random**) images from folder with hikari in python and can help me edit my code

```
@lightbulb.command('img', 'image')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def image(ctx):
    f = hikari.File('C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder/file.jpg')
    await ctx.respond(f)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
images = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")
def select_random_image_path():
    return os.path.join(images, random.choice(os.listdir(images)))

@lightbulb.command('img', 'image')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.PrefixCommand)
async def image(ctx):
    f = hikari.File(select_random_image_path())
    await ctx.respond(f)
```

If your file structure looks like below:

```
|   main.py
+---images
|       73doCML.jpg
|       BcAyMo7.jpg
|       eRcYeHL.jpg
|       HSlG1Gl.jpg
|       IDgfXn6.jpg
|       ljFuj1z.jpg
|       MmBXwZN.jpg
|       N0udyAV.jpg
|       xenAlf8.png
|       yc1kX4A.jpg
|       ZJubdTU.jpg
```